# Macros Libreoffice Calc - No puedo ingresar los datos del array en las celdas

Tags: macros, basic, libreoffice-calc

Hola buenas despues de un buen rato leyendo y probando no me sale,( con la biblia de Pitonyak en mano) no logro que los datos de array se inserten en otra hoja ( los datos los obtengo como columna y los debo pegar como fila)

Gracias de Antemano

```
'Insertamos los datos en las celdas Obtenemos solo los datos del array
DatosEgresos = oEgresos.getDataArray   

x=1 ' variable contador para moverse atraves de las columnas
For Contador = 0 to 15

oHojaEgresos.getCellByPosition(x , 3).setString(DatosEgresos(Contador,0)) ' Ingreso de los datos a la celdas
MsgBox DatosEgresos(Contador)(0)
x = 1 + x
Next

Dim Parar as Object
```

Aqui muestro que la variable datros egreso si tiene datos y los muestra en MsgBox Pero no los puedo ingresar en la celda que deseo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Datos de Referencia

Answer (score 0):

Debería ser así, ¿no?

```
oHojaEgresos.getCellByPosition(x , 3).setString(DatosEgresos(Contador)(0))
```

Creo que el problema es que para acceder a las matrices, los paréntesis deben ser como `(a) (b)` en lugar de su código que tiene `(a, b)`. Esta es como su línea con `MsgBox`.